# Power pack and servo driver for robotic arm?

Tags: robotic-arm, servomotor, torque, battery, driver

I have a robotic arm that uses about eight 7.4 volt volt high torque servos. (https://www.servocity.com/2000-series-dual-mode-servo-25-2/)

I need to know what Kind of battery system I can use to power the claw servos, and what servo controllers are available for such a heavy duty servo type.

BATTERY OPTIONS:
I cant use lead acid, because my robot cant fit such a massive battery on it. Li-ion I'm not sure would work, because each cell is 3.7v, and the max amp-hours for a typical battery cell is 5Ah so the battery pack for All the servos would be 2 li-ion batteries, and 10Ah, which would very quickly drain the cells.

I'm guessing my best option would be to make a NiCd D-cell battery pack, resulting in 5 NiCd batteries 1.2v each and 25Ah.

SERVO CONTROLLER:
I am not sure what servo controllers are the best for controlling 7v servos. I have one that can control small 5v servos, but I dont know if it could handle the heavy duty servos that are on my claw.

Comment: the servo controller is the same as for a light duty servo, probably even a cheap hobby servo ... please investigate how servo controller controls the servo

Comment: I do not think your battery calculations/assumptions are correct. You either put batteries (cells) in series to increase voltage or you put them in parallel to increase electric charge. You can do both, but you need more batteries